# How to display value from another Store in Grid cell?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4

I have Cars grid which displays all my cars. It's bound to Cars store (which is bound to Car model).

Car model has `brand_id` field which points on certain Car brand.

So in the Grid I have numeric `brand_id` in my Brand column.

I have a store:

```
Ext.define('1.store.Brands', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['id', 'title'],
    data : [
        {'id':1, 'title':'AUDI'},
        {'id':2, 'title':'BMW'},
        {'id':3, 'title':'FIAT'}
    ]

});
```

How display real brand title instead of it's `ID` automatically pulling it from Brands store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your brands store in grid column renderer.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer

```
{
    renderer: function(value){
        var rec = brandStore.findRecord('id', value);
        return rec.get("title");    
    }
}
```